# How to include symbolic information (DWARF) in binary in package.yaml based project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How to enable symbolic DWARF information in binary with "package.yaml" file? I found [this](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#dwarf) but I can not understand how to pass all those options through "package.yaml" file.

Comment: you could enable it in global `~/.cabal/config`. It seems [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) doesn't support the flags yet.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with "stack.yaml" ?

Comment: Probably no. Otherwise [stack's documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#dwarf) would mention it.